# Is it possible in c# to write a binary file with a file size that is not divisible by 4?

Tags: c#, binaryfiles, system.io.file

I am trying to use c# to create a binary file (which I am using to mod a game) that is 506 KB. However, no matter what I try, the file size always comes out to be something divisible by 4 (which 506 is unfortunately not). For example, I have gotten the resulting file to be 504 KB. I have gotten it to be 508 KB. However, I can not get it to be 506 KB. Is there a way to make it so that your resulting file size does not have to be divisible by 4? Here is an example of something that I've tried (that still ends up yielding a file of size 504 KB):

```
int k = 1024 * 506; //because there are 1024 bytes in a KB and I want 506 KB` `

 BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(System.IO.File.OpenWrite("path"));
            
 for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)`
 {
   writer.Write(Convert.ToByte(false));
 }
```

Comment: You've left out some important information here.  1.  Why do you need it to be not divisible by 4?  2.  What is in the extra bytes?

Comment: Also, there's some uncertainty with respect to your units.  Kilobytes or KibiBytes?  Is it really the size you say, or are you reading the wrong units?

Comment: 1K=1024, 1024/4 = 256, so xK can always be divided by 4.

Comment: Depending on your compiler options and the type of microprocessor the alignment can be different causing the binary being a different size.

Comment: How do you know the size of the file? Show us a screenshot of the properties dialog showing the file size- file size and size on disk may be two different things and you may not be looking at the right one

Comment: How are you checking the size? Note that Windows, for instance, fudges the numbers when reporting file size.

Comment: 506KB *is* divisible by 4. Did you mean it must be a multiple of 4K?

Comment: A better metric to discuss would be the exact number of bytes written.

Comment: I tried your code (just added `writer.Close` at the end) and cannot reproduce your problem. Here is what the file details say: `Size: 506 KB (518.144 bytes), Size on disk: 508 KB (520.192)`. Looks fine to me, 518144 is exactly 1024*506. The size on disk is obviously larger, since [NTFS has a default cluster size of 4KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/140365/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat).

Comment: The operating system works with units called "clusters."  It's going to round up to your cluster size.

Comment: So.  Given all these comments, does your file *really* have to not be a multiple of 4?

Answer (score 2):

My guess for this is that you've written your file to a disk that has 4kb clusters:

[image]

Incidentally, `File.WriteAllBytes(path, new byte[506 * 1024])` is possibly a more succinct and performant way to write exactly 518144 zero bytes to disk, than one-by-one'ing conversion of false to byte..

Answer (score 0):

I just tried adding `writer.close()` to my code and that worked like a charm. I got the 506 KB file that I needed.